# Using an explicit localization expression for a page title?

Tags: c#, asp.net, page-title

I am trying to get an explicit localization expression for a page title, but can't seem to figure out how, and a google search comes up with nothing.

With a control, it's nice and easy:

```
<asp:literal runat="server" text="<%$ Resources:MyResource, StringId %>" />
```

But how does one do this for the page title?  I've tried specifying it in the page directive, but that of course doesn't work:

```
<%@ Page Title="<%$ Resources:MyResource, StringId %>" ...
```

Is there a way to do this? Or is it simply not possible?

Comment: I should note: this page has a master file (so I can't specify in the <title> tag), and if at all possible, I'd like the title to be changeable through the designer (so programmatic assignment won't do the trick)

Comment: Well I feel kinda silly... <%@ Page Title="<%$ Resources:MyResource, StringId %>" actually DOES work.  The reason it wasn't working for me was that I have a custom FileLevelPageControlBuilder.

Thanks everyone for the tips!

Answer (score 3):

You can also use either

```
Page.Title = Resources.MyResource.StringId;
```

or

```
<title><%= Resources.MyResource.StringId %></title>
```

Comment: The first suggestion won't allow me to change the value in the designer though, correct?
And the 2nd suggestion won't work if I'm using a master?

Comment: First one is code-behind. What you can do, is add a content placeholder in the head of the master page and then set the title tag like example 2 in the placeholder area in your child page.

Comment: Hmm interesting thought, thanks Teos!
So I'm guessing this means there's no built-in way to use a resource binding expression in the page directive?

Comment: I don't think so. There's no way to really reference it in the directive. I usually just handle the page title from the code-behind. :)

Answer (score -1):

simply in the page load event write

```
Page.Title="any String u want";
```

Comment: The OP is asking for explicit localization.