# The $ sign in ASP.NET programming?

Tags: asp.net, syntax, explicit

When does this $ sign come into the picture? It bothers me. What is its significance?

```
<asp:literal runat="server" text="<%$ Resources:MyResource, StringId %>" />
```

as seen in this thread:

[Using an explicit localization expression for a page title?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644809/using-an-explicit-localization-expression-for-a-page-title)

Does this kind of .NET syntax have a name? I'm guessing it only works for a certain asp.net version (i.e. asp.net 3.5)? Much thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It means that what comes after the dollar is an expression, see [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5bd1tad.aspx). It works in .net 3 & 4

Answer (score 1):

The example you posted is documented here:  [ASP.NET Expressions Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5bd1tad.aspx)

It's used for expression binding, usually with localized string resources.

Answer (score 0):

The `$` expression binding allow us to extract custom application settings, connection string and resource information from configuration and resource files respectively.

The $ expression is a code sequence that processes the expression and replaces it with a string value in the final HTML.